# How to use Jemalloc memory allocator only for a certain process on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, memory-management, jemalloc

I am using `Jemalloc` on Ubuntu 20.04 for my nodejs apps using `export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so` and it works really well. However I am not able to benefit from it with `Chromium-browser` and I run into

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

Is there anyway I can only use `Jemalloc` for `nodejs` apps and not get it involved with other processes on the server?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @EugeneLorman I ended up using Chromium instead of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

With the [`env` helper](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html):

```
env LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so node myapp.js
```

(where `node myapp.js` is your app - could as well be `npm start` or whatever.)

Comment: env LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so pm2 start app.js runs however ps aux | grep node and cat /proc/5834/smaps | grep jemalloc indicates I am not running it with Jemalloc and with export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so pm2 start app.js I run into -bash: export: `app.js': not a valid identifier